# Any ideas as to why the new code slows down the ray-tracer?

Tags: c++, performance, raytracing

I am doing a ray-tracer and I implemented perspective correction, calculating the positions of rays to be launched from using the current pixel values in the x and y axes to calculate the current ray direction.
Here the code piece:

```
float fov = 60; 
float invWidth = 1/float(image.getWidth());
float invHeight = 1/float(image.getHeight());
float angle = (fov * M_PI * 0.5/180 );
float aspectratio = image.getWidth()/float(image.getHeight());
point camera = scene.getCamera();
for (int y=0;  y<image.getHeight(); y++) { 
  for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++) {
    ......
    ......
    float xx = (((x*invWidth) *2)-1) * angle * aspectratio; 
    float yy = (((y*invHeight)*2)-1) * angle;
    Ray viewRay = { {camera.x, camera.y, camera.z}, {xx, yy, 1.0f}};
```

So far, so good it works perfectly. However I realized that the values of xx and yy (the direction of the pixels) doesn't need to be calculated for every pixel, only a couple of times equal to the width and length of the image.
So I rewrote these part on this way:

```
float fov = 60; 
float invWidth = 1/float(image.getWidth());
float invHeight = 1/float(image.getHeight());
float angle = (fov * M_PI * 0.5/180 );
float aspectratio = image.getWidth()/float(image.getHeight());
float rays_x [image.getWidth()], rays_y [image.getHeight()];
for (int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++)
    rays_y [y] = (((y*invHeight)*2)-1) * angle;
for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++)
    rays_x [x] = (((x*invWidth) *2)-1) * angle * aspectratio;
point camera = scene.getCamera();
for (int y=0;  y<image.getHeight(); y++) { 
  float yy = rays_y[y];
  for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++) {
    ......
    ......
    Ray viewRay = { {camera.x, camera.y, camera.z}, {rays_x[x], yy, 1.0f}};
```

I basically pre-computed the directions of the rays and stored them into arrays. I expected small improvements in performance, maybe nothing in a pessimistic case, but I never expected it to get WORST.
Before I was taking1.67s to render a scene and now it takes 1.74! Not a massive fall but surprising seeing that I expected to be doing a lot less work now. I disabled compiler optimizations (-O3 and -ffast-math) and tested with the two approaches. Before it tooked between 9.03 and 9.05, and now goes between 9.06 and 9.15

So how should I investigate the matter? The only thing that crossed my mind is less cache hits due to access rays_x [x] every loop iteration and rays_y [y] every 1024 iterations, although I would never suspect that, because it is only 1024*4=4096+(768*4)=7168 bytes in the total. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? How is the performance now? Do you need any further help?

Comment: I'm not sure you are implementing it the right way, but you can also initialize the variables outside the loops: `float xx, xxstart=-angle*aspectratio, yy=-angle, xstep=angle*aspectratio*2*invwidth, ystep=angle*2*invheight;` and then update the values inside the loops: `xx = xxstart; ... yy += ystep; ... xx += xstep;`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will realize that this one:

```
float yy = (((y*invHeight)*2)-1) * angle;
```

is constant data, and only needs to be calculated once per loop.

Therefore, your precomputed yy is a waste of performance.

Precomputed xx could help though, but if the expression constains much constant data (i.e. **invWidth * 2** and **angle * aspectratio**) the performance may not increase and may even get worse due to cache misses.

```
float xx = (((x*invWidth) *2)-1) * angle * aspectratio;
```

Answer (score 0):

Precomputing the directions will accelerate your tracer. But there is obviously an overhead of creating the lookup-table in the first place. In your code you are creating the tables on the stack and recomputing the directions for every frame. This will be slightly slower because you have to read from the array which you previously didnt and because of the memory allocation overhead. Instead i would suggest you create your lookup arrays on the heap (as pointer outside the method) and precompute your directions only once.
The directions are dependent on values that dont change between frames, so there is no need to compute the directions every frame.

Something like this:

```
float *rays_x, *rays_y;

void compute_directions()
{
    rays_x = new float[image.getWidth()];
    rays_y = new float[image.getHeight()];
    for (int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++)
        rays_y[y] = (((y*invHeight)*2)-1) * angle;
    for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++)
        rays_x[x] = (((x*invWidth) *2)-1) * angle * aspectratio;
}

void render()
{
    float fov = 60; 
    float invWidth = 1/float(image.getWidth());
    float invHeight = 1/float(image.getHeight());
    float angle = (fov * M_PI * 0.5/180 );
    float aspectratio = image.getWidth()/float(image.getHeight());
    point camera = scene.getCamera();
    for (int y=0;  y<image.getHeight(); y++) { 
    float yy = rays_y[y];
    for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++) {
        ......
        ......
```

You obviously have to move angle and aspectratio to somewhere else, so you can access them in compute_directions.
Also remember to delete your pointers with delete[] if you dont need them anymore to prevent a memoroy leak.

Comment: The overhead for memory allocation on the stack is negligible, it's just moving the stack pointer, chances are this is happening anyway and it would just be by a different number,

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description, it seems you *optimized* on a hunch by precomputing some values that seem to be computed very fast (shifting the computation to some memory lookups that might not yield any performance improvements - also, this is a hunch!).

Some basic rules on optimization:

- Before trying optimize anything: profile.
- After optimizing anything: profile.

You cannot expect any performance gain from optimizing before knowing where your program actually spends time.

On Linux you can use [GCCs -pg switch and gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Compiling.html). You can also use [perf](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4q5518/introduction_to_linux_performance_analysis_using/) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (e.g. callgrind to get an idea of the number of calls to a particular function).

Also check out the [perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).